# How can I generate both Entity and EntityHistory tables for each DbSet<ٍEntity>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How can I generate both Entity and EntityHistory tables for each DbSet<ٍEntity>?
EntityHistory table is automatically created after inheriting from BaseEntity class or An Interface and no DbSet is defined for it.

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet Entity{ get; set; }

```
public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```

}

I want to have two tables named Entity and EntityHistory created automatically after creating a Migration, with EntityHistory being completely generated automatically.

please help me!

https://github.com/Arch/AutoHistory
I found this Library, but it creates a History for all DBSets. I want to have a separate History for each Entity.

Comment: What is the main question? How to generate entity classes from other entities? If you are using SQL Server, you can use existing functionality [Temporal Tables](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/)